# Crystal reports -Custom grouping

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table called  `Employee(EmployeeNo,name,Address)`.Employee number is integer. Employee numbers
prefix is changes according to employees working location. for example 

EmployeeNumber - Location
12323          -  London  prefix "1" says that employee location is in London 
24343          -  Newyork prefix "2" says that employee location is in Newyork 
38989          -  Moscow  prefix "3" says that employee location is in Moscow.

Now my problem is I don't have separate field to group employee by there location in crystal reports. so I have to get each employee's location using his employee number and group it according to that.

example
London
12323 Thomas sx 
13434 Ray    xx 
14343 Frank  uy

NewYork 
24545 Alan oo 
26656 Robin op 
29098 Hayden lp

Moskow 
35424 gustov lo 
38967 Levshev ol

any idea is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here compulsory scenario should be "Prefix" should be first letter of the location

Use the below code in a formula

```
Left (<database field>,1 )
```

Now use the formula to group.

You should be able to group according to lcoation

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I converted the integer database field to text.It works fine